# What is the last argument of the previous command?

Tags: bash

`$_` is said to be the last argument of the previous command.

So I wonder why it is not `EDITOR="emacs -nw"` but `EDITOR` in the following example?

Why isn't `"emacs -nw"` part of the last argument?

More generally, what are the definitions of an argument, and the last argument?

Thanks.

```
$ export EDITOR="emacs -nw"
$ echo $_
EDITOR
```

Comment: I think it's for the same reason that shellcheck tells you not to export variables on the same line you assign them.  The assignment happens and then the variable is exported.  `EDITOR` is an argument to export

Comment: FWIW, `pdksh` and `dash` will include the value that was assigned, but `ksh93` will behave as `bash` does.

Comment: zsh: `export FOO=bar; echo $_`, prints `export`.

Comment: @Jesse_b The whole thing is the last argument/operand (including the value assigned), but it may have something to do with the fact that `export` is a built-in utility.

Comment: ksh: `typeset -x FOO=bar` then `echo $_` prints `FOO`, but in Bash `declare -x FOO=bar; echo $_` prints `FOO=bar`.

Comment: @Kusalananda I think experimental evidence from my answer bears out Jesse_b's hypothesis.

Comment: @Jesse_b Thanks. I was wondering why "not to export variables on the same line you assign them"

Comment: @Jesse_b https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/438236/why-not-to-export-variables-on-the-same-line-you-assign-them

Answer (score 13):

Bash processes variable assignments, when they’re allowed as arguments (with `alias`, `declare`, `export`, `local`, `readonly`, and `typeset`), before anything else (or rather, it identifies them before anything else — expansion applies to the values assigned to variables). When it gets to word expansion, the remaining command is `export EDITOR`, so `_` is set to `EDITOR`.

Generally speaking, arguments are the “words” remaining after expansion (which doesn’t include variable assignments and redirections).

See [Simple command expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Simple-Command-Expansion.html#Simple-Command-Expansion) in the Bash manual for details.

Comment: And I realise `declare`’s behaviour doesn’t match what I’m describing...

Comment: Well, it's not very consistent in that. `declare a=b; echo $_` prints `a=b`; `export c=d; echo $_` prints just `c`. `alias` seems to print just the name, `local` on the other hand prints the whole argument. And `readonly` also prints just the name, which I found a bit surprising since I would have thought  `readonly` and `local` would be similar to `declare`.

Comment: @ilkkachu heh, I realised that too (see above). `export` and `readonly` are declared together in `setattr.def`, `declare`, `local`, and `typeset` are declared in `declare.def`, `alias` stands alone in `alias.def`.

Comment: Thanks. When variable assignments are used as arguments to some commands, (1) "(or rather, it identifies them before anything else — expansion applies to the values assigned to variables)", do you mean expansion happens to the values before performing variable assignment? (2) "When it gets to word expansion, the remaining command is export EDITOR", do you mean performing variable assignment happens before expansion? The two quotes seem to contradict   each other.

Comment: Thanks. I am a little confused. When variable assignments are used as arguments to`alias, declare, export, local, readonly` and `typeset`. What happen first and next? "When it gets to word expansion, the remaining command is `export EDITOR`", do you imply that variable assignment `EDITOR="emacs -nw"` happens before expansion? If not, why the remaining command doesn't contain the assignment as argument? If yes,  doesn't expansion on the values assigned to the variables have to happen before performing the variable assignment?

Comment: I assume the link you gave to bash manual doesn't apply to the cases when assignments are arguments to the mentioned commands. Am I correct?

Comment: Bash manual says `_` "expands to the last argument to the previous command, after expansion."  Why after "expansion", the remaining command is `export EDITOR` instead of `export EDITOR="emacs -nw"`? There doesn't seem to be anything needed to be expanded.

Comment: I'd appreciate if you could elaborate or rephrase somehow. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: In the case of `export FOO=bar`, bash invokes its temporary environment creation, sets `FOO=bar` in that environment, then yields a final command of `export FOO`. At that point, `FOO` is taken as the last argument.

---

Ah, the much-abused [`$_`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html):

> ($_, an underscore.) At shell startup, set to the absolute pathname used to invoke the shell or shell script being executed as passed in the environment or argument list. Subsequently, expands to the last argument to the previous command, after expansion. Also set to the full pathname used to invoke each command executed and placed in the environment exported to that command. When checking mail, this parameter holds the name of the mail file.

Let's look at a few variations:

```
$ man; echo $_
What manual page do you want?
man
$ man foo; echo $_
No manual entry for foo
foo
$ echo; echo $_

echo
$ echo bar foo; echo $_
bar foo
foo
$ foo=x eval 'echo $foo'; echo $_
x
echo $foo
$ bar() { man $1; }; echo $_
foo
$ for (( i=0; $i<0; i=i+1 )); do echo $i; done; echo $_
foo
$ bar; echo $_
What manual page do you want?
man
$ bar foo; echo $_
No manual entry for foo
foo
$ MANPATH=/tmp; echo $_

$ export MANPATH=/tmp; echo $_
MANPATH
```

So we see three patterns here:

- Commands invoked from the filesystem, functions, and built-ins behave as generally expected: `$_` is set to the command name itself if no arguments, otherwise the last of the presented arguments.
- After function definitions, loops, and other logical constructions: `$_` is not modified.
- Everything else: `$_` is set to something not quite expected; weird.

I've instrumented the code to provide some insight into the weirdness.

```
$ ./bash --noprofile --norc -c 'man foo'
lastword=[man]
lastarg=[foo]
$ ./bash --noprofile --norc -c 'export FOO=bar'
lastword=[export]
lastarg=[FOO=bar]
bind_variable, name=[FOO], value=[bar]
before bind_lastarg, lastarg=[FOO]
bind_lastarg, arg=[FOO]
bind_variable, name=[_], value=[FOO]
$ ./bash --noprofile --norc -c 'declare FOO=bar'
lastword=[declare]
lastarg=[FOO=bar]
bind_variable, name=[FOO], value=[(null)]
before bind_lastarg, lastarg=[FOO=bar]
bind_lastarg, arg=[FOO=bar]
bind_variable, name=[_], value=[FOO=bar]
```

You can see that the *parser* sees the expected last argument (`lastarg=`) in all cases, but what happens thereafter depends on what bash thinks should happen. See [execute_cmd.c, execute_simple_command()](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/execute_cmd.c#n4009).

In the case of `export FOO=bar`, bash makes the assignment and then exports the variable. This seems consistent with the documentation’s assertion that last argument calculated after expansion.

Comment: How does the shell know you are checking mail?

Comment: @rackandboneman without confirming, I suspect the internal checks done based on `MAILCHECK`

Answer (score 3):

To answer the title question, try `!$`:

```
$ export EDITOR="emacs -nw"
$ echo !$
EDITOR=emacs -nw
```

This is history expansion. From the bash manpage:

> History  expansion  is  performed  immediately after a complete line is
>   read, before the shell breaks it into words.  It  takes  place  in  two
>   parts.   The  first is to determine which line from the history list to
>   use during substitution.  The second is to select portions of that line
>   for inclusion into the current one.  The line selected from the history
>   is the event, and the portions of that line that  are  acted  upon  are
>   words.

...

> Event Designators

...

> !      Start  a  history substitution, except when followed by a blank,
>         newline, carriage return, = or ( (when the extglob shell  option
>         is enabled using the shopt builtin).

...

> !!     Refer to the previous command.
>   This is a synonym for `!-1'.

...

> Word Designators

...

> $      The  last  word.   This  is  usually the last argument, but will
>         expand to the zeroth word if there is only one word in the line.

...

> If a word designator is supplied without an  event  specification,  the
>   previous command is used as the event.

Comment: You’re taking the title of the question waaaaay too literally.  (OK, it’s a poor title.)  We all can see that the command «`export EDITOR="emacs -nw"`» consists of two words: the first is «`export`» and the second is «``EDITOR="emacs -nw"``».  The question is really asking, “What do the bash man page and the Bash Manual mean when they say that `!_` ‘expands to the last argument to the previous command’, given that bash sets `$_` to «`EDITOR`» in this case?”  Copying and pasting the bash man page section on history expansion is not particularly helpful.