# Why not to export variables on the same line you assign them?

Tags: bash

From [What is the last argument of the previous command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/437261/what-is-the-last-argument-of-the-previous-command#comment790172_437261)

> shellcheck tells you not to export variables on the same line you assign them.

I was wondering why?

Does the same advice apply to `alias`, `declare`, `export`, `local`, `readonly`, and `typeset`?

Comment: See also [Why is it not required to double quote \`$bar\` in assignment \`foo=$bar\`?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/383770)

Comment: And [Are quotes needed for local variable assignment?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/97569)

Comment: The shellcheck rule in question is SC2155. There is pretty good documentation at the shellcheck [wiki](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2155).

Comment: Also some older shells wouldn't accept `export` and assignment together. The [Heirloom Bourne Shell](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh.html), for example, outputs a "foo=2 is not an identifier" error.

Answer (score 56):

The [problem](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2155) is that in Bash every command has only one exit code. When you `export foo="$(false)"` the exit code of `false` is simply discarded. If you instead do

```
foo="$(false)"
export foo
```

the failing first command can be acted upon, for example by the `errexit` setting.

Declaring and assigning a string literal such as `export foo='bar'` does of course not suffer from this problem. But change is the only constant in software development, and it's simply good housekeeping to future-proof such statements by splitting them up.

In addition to the assignment specific commands you mention there's also multiple commands in a single assignment such as `foo="$(false)$(true)"`. See [`pipefail`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) in `man bash` for yet another such trap.

Another thing to remember is that the sequence of declaration and assignment is sometimes relevant. For example, you'll want to declare variables [`local`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-local) *before* assigning them. (Unfortunately it's not possible to declare variables [`readonly`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-readonly) before assigning them for the first time.)

Comment: So if one is setting a variable from a literal, and there's no exit code to discard, there's nothing wrong with doing it all on one line.

Comment: As far as this shellcheck error is concerned, no.  But as now-deleted answers got half-right between them, the Bourne shell did not support the assignment syntax for `export`, so for some years there was received wisdom about doing this if one's interpreter was likely to be the Bourne shell.

Comment: @JdeBP, note that the Bourne shell did support `foo=$(cmd) export foo`, though with the same caveat that `cmd`'s exit status is lost (but did cause the shell to exit if failing with `set -e`).

Comment: That was covered by my first sentence.